# How to extract useful features from time-series data (e.g., users' daily activities in a forum)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, feature-extraction

I have data regarding users' visits and postings in a discussion forum for a 1-week period, and this data contains the timestamp of the activity. Based on this forum data, I tried to predict users' another behavior (let's say `X` behavior). Initial results of the regression model show that users' forum activity seem to be associated with their `X` behavior. Besides these cumulative features: **avg_visits_per_day**, **total_posts_whole_week**, I also have features for each day (`0<a<8`): **{a}_visits** and **{a}_posts**.

Thus, I have 16 features in total, and the regression model built with these 16 features gives promising results. So, it would make more sense if I can generate more features. However, I do not know if there any useful feature-extraction strategy for such time-series data. I am using `sklearn` but did not see a method for this purpose. Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options, an it's difficult to suggest which ones are more useful for predicting the unknown "x behaviour". However, you could:

1. Manually create features representing information that's clearly available in raw data, but not present in you current feature set at all. For example, if you have not only dates, but also times of activity logged - you can construct additional features for first/last/average time of visiting within each day (maybe converted to categorical morning/day/evening/night), average time between visits and so on. Probably day of week information could be useful as well.
2. Manually create relative features from existing set: say, visits/posts ratio for each day, number of days since last post, longest period without visits, etc
3. Use additional information if it's available: user's browser, OS, screen resolution, post length, keywords present in his/her post, subforum it belongs to, new post or follow-up, ... - once again, it's hard to tell beforehand what will be relevant.
4. Do automated feature extraction by package like [tsfresh](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh) or (less automated) [hctsa](https://github.com/benfulcher/hctsa)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! I believe by `day of week information`, you mean sth like `1th` or `5th` activities?

Comment: You are welcome. By day of week I mean the following: 
if your week doesn't always start on the same day (i.e. {1}_visits and {1}_posts could be visits/posts logged on Sunday for one user and Monday for another one), making this information available to prediction algoritm could improve its results.